# Как изменить тип input при клике?

Tags: vue.js

Есть input в котором изначально указан type="password"
По нажатию на кнопку нужно изменить тип на text.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Не надо ничего заменять. Скройте инпут пароля и покажите инпут текстовый.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня внутри инпута есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую, пароль должен быть виден.

Comment: И что это меняет?

Comment: Ну а в целом https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp    ... правда не знаю как это для vue  будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас стоит в теге `vue`. Поэтому даю ответ как сделать это на `vue`.

Вам нужно установить на кнопку событие клик, при которой будет выполнятся функция  `@click="clickBtn"`.

В `data()` добавить флаг для простоты решения `isFlag: true` .

Далее в `methods` записываете `this.isFlag = !this.isFlag`.  И с помощью тернарного оператора в инпуте выводите  `:type="isFlag ? 'password' : 'text'"`.

Все вместе выглядит так:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputType: '',
      isFlag: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickBtn() {
      this.isFlag = !this.isFlag
      console.log(this.isFlag)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input :type="isFlag ? 'password' : 'text'">
  <button @click="clickBtn">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: именно так и решил!)
ниже в ответе описал ход решения.
Вы же реализовали его.
Спасибо!)

Comment: @Stanislavkm я даже не заметил, вашего ответа если честно. Оставлю вдруг кому пригодится. На будущее если пишите ответ на свой вопрос, оформляйте его как ответ, и помечайте галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать два инпута. password и text. Повешай обработчки на password, который при нажати на него скроет password и покажет text

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:
Переменную задать булевскую. При клике на кнопку менять с true на false. type инпута связать с этой переменной ( если true, то в type записывать password, false-text).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleViewPass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
Password: <input type="password" value="pass" id="myInput">

<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleViewPass()">Show Pass
```